# <webview> tag not working Chrome Packaged Extensions

Tags: google-chrome, webview

Anyone have any advice about getting  to work in Chrome Packaged Apps? I have followed everything in the tutorials, and my webview doesn't load the URL, but the container shows up. I used horrible colours on purpose so I could see the frames (sorry in advance)

Manifest.JSON - http://pastebin.com/dkDx3qUr
Window.html - http://pastebin.com/RBQZ5MNG

Any advice you could give would be great!

Google Chrome Version 4.0.1312.57 m

Comment: The pastebin's are no longer present.  Please update the question with new code.

Answer (score 0):

Sadly, your pastebin is outdated, but I guess the problem is your packaged app is a legacy packaged apps.

To fix that, convert this:

```
"app": {
  "launch": {
    "local_path": "browser.html"
  }
},
```

to this:

```
"app": {
  "background": {
  "scripts": ["main.js"]
  }
},
```

main.js should then contain this:

```
chrome.app.runtime.onLaunched.addListener(runApp);
chrome.app.runtime.onRestarted.addListener(runApp);

function runApp() {
  window.open("browser.html");
};
```